# How can we make a Python script auto executable at system startup (preferably linux) on every system it is installed on?

Tags: python, linux, autoexec

I have a python script , it has to be auto - executed on startup. I know how to make it happen in my system through editing and adding files in etc/init.d .  I have created a Python Package for it with setup.py and other files but I cant find a way how to make the script auto executable on every system that it is installed . Is there a way to do it using setup.py ?

Comment: there are many ways you can do it. For example cronjob would a way to auto execute with the paramet `onboot`. You don't need setup.py to autoexecute a script.

Comment: @Oz123 : But if it is installed on a new system , will it automatically run on it ? I can configure and create cronjob on my machine but can it be replicated on every machine installed on ?

Comment: yes. You just need to distribute the script on a consitent location

Comment: @Oz123 Thanks a lot. Will try implementing it :)

Answer (score -1):

Put that script in /etc/rc.local to execute it every time you boot the system.